# audio via Jack only with omxplayer

Tags: audio, output

Strange things happen to my Pi. I have a headphone connected to the audio output (3.5jack). I have added the snd_bcm2835 modules and when I start a track on the omxplayer via ssh, music comes in top quality.

Unfortunately, the omxplayer can not create a playlist so I would use moc. But thing comes out. Also with other audio programs not. `Aplay`  also does not play the test tone. `Aplay -l` says that no sound card is availbe ... in the alsamixer I can not select an alternative sound card.

But why omxplayer works?

Can anyone tell me how I get the audio jack to run?